# Empty dataframe when filtering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

Now I'd like to filter like this:

```
df1.loc[df1['PZAE'] == 'HAE']
```

However, I am getting an empty dataframe.
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `df1.loc[df1['PZAE']=="'HAE'"]`

Details :

the column `'PZAE'` contains `str` starting and finishing by `'` that's why you have to include them in the condition

Answer (score 4):

@Pi-R's answer is probably what you are looking for, but in case it is useful, you can also match partial strings like so:

```
df1.loc[df1['PZAE'].str.contains('HAE')]
```

That should also give you what you want here.